# RSA encryption using public key on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, public-key-encryption

I have seen an example of encrypting a string with a Java Midlet, using a public key which is a byte array.

I am not able to do that on a BlackBerry, because there is no X509EncodedKeySpec and Cipher classes to hold the public key.

How is this done on BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1):

RIM's BlackBerry knowledge center has some useful articles about this:

[How to - Use Basic Encryption](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800779/How_to_-_Use_Basic_Encryption.html?nodeid=800640&vernum=0)

[How to - Use Advanced Encryption](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800779/How_to_-_Use_Advanced_Encryption.html?nodeid=800439&vernum=0)

Comment: here is the difference for both AES and RSA.. private static byte[] encrypt( byte[] keyData, byte[] data )
        throws CryptoException, IOException
    {
        // Create the AES key to use for encrypting the data.
        // This will create an AES key using as much of the keyData
        // as possible.
        AESKey key = new AESKey( keyData );} where RSA is not allowing to give the keyData that is my problem can u help me in this ..i have to use RSA please help me